# cake php element cache

Tags: cakephp, caching

I can't make element caching work:

```
echo $this->element('categorytree', array(
    'cache' => array(
        'key'=>'categorytree-cache','time' => '+1 hour'
    )
))
```

I checked core.php:

```
// In development mode, caches should expire quickly.
$duration = '+999 days';
/*if (Configure::read('debug') >= 1) {
    $duration = '+10 seconds';
}*/
```

And commented as you see - to prevent short caching in debug mode...

But still when I refresh page the SQL query that cached element does by requestAction() is shown... So no caching... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but I think the correct call would be:

```
echo $this->element('categorytree', array(), array(
    'cache' => array(
        'key'=>'categorytree-cache','time' => '+1 hour'
    )
))
```

Notice the second argument is element *params* while the third is element *options* (what you need here).

You can see the function signature [here](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/view#line-270).